# Stocks by sector on italian market?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets, online-tools

I need the list of all stocks exchanged on italian market by sector: chemistry, goods.

**It would be enough the list of actions divided by sector.**

The aim is to study what are the "best" (in my opinion) stocks for each sector make analysis by myself

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please. It is unclear if you want online tools, or a source of data with stocks by sector, or a tool that does the analysis for you. You are/will be getting down votes because you question isnt very clear.

Comment: I rewrite the question. I need the list of stocks exchanged on italian market by sectors

Comment: https://screener.finance.yahoo.com/stocks.html

Comment: @Ross this will be right if it is possible to set the filter by market (italian in my case)

Comment: @ale try [http://stockscreener.us.reuters.com/Stock/US/Index?quickscreen=gaarp](http://stockscreener.us.reuters.com/Stock/US/Index?quickscreen=gaarp) it has a filter by region.

Comment: http://www.milanofinanza.it/ has the filter I need

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done within the site of your broker.  Here are a list of some common brokerages:

http://www.stockbrokers.com/onlinestockbrokers.html

For example, if you choose Fidelity, you go to their research center: 
https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/landing.jhtml
https://research2.fidelity.com/fidelity/screeners/commonstock/landing.asp?

where you can easily screen stocks by sector, dividend yield, EPS, market cap, etc.

If you don't have an online brokerage account, you can usually sign up for free and you can usually use their proprietary research tools without even having to fund your account!